# How do I format time and bypass server name?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So I am about to post ALOT but I have been cracking at this for days now and can't get passed it. Basically with the code below I am trying to change the time format and also trying to fix null error which I don't think I can with what I call.

ERROR #1 ------------------------------

```
(node:8844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
at Object.execute (C:\filepath\bot\commands\serverinfo.js:22:39)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\filepath\bot\main.js:54:43)
at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\filepath\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\filepath\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)        
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\filepath\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\filepath\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\filepath\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\filepath\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
```

(node:8844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8844) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
non-zero exit code.

What I have come to conclude is that it can't pull the server name for a DM of course but I don't know how to break the below code where it only loads the DM portion and then the channel portion separate? I have tried 2 separate .js files and the DM one sends but not the server?

Error #2 ------------------------------

I am trying to change the time and date format so it is not so long. Below is what my output is currently and what I am trying to get. I have been trying to work with moment.js but it doesn't seem to work properly for me?

[output I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9SPN.png)

And what I am hoping to get is just MM/DD/YYYY. If someone could help me out I would be beyond grateful.

CODE -------------

```
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');
module.exports = {  
    name: 'serverinfo',
    description: 'sends the serverinfo command',
    execute(message, args) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const user = message.author;
    var moment = require('moment'); // require
    const keepinservercommandembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    .setTitle('**Im Sorry!**')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/7Gvh8VL.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: `**Can` + `'t accept: ${prefix}serverinfo**`, value: 'Please keep the commands to the server!' },
    )
    if(message.channel.type == "dm") {
        message.channel.send(keepinservercommandembed);
    }
    const serverinfocommandembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0000FF')
    .setTitle(`**"${message.guild.name}" Server Information**`)
    .setDescription('Per your request here is a little bit of information about the server we you invoked this command in:')
    .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
    .addFields(
        { name: '**Server Owner**:', value: `${message.guild.owner}`, inline: true },
        { name: '**Joined On**:', value: `${message.member.joinedAt}`, inline: true },
        { name: '**Total Members**:', value: `${message.guild.memberCount}`, inline: true },
        { name: '**Role Count**:', value: `${message.guild.roles.cache.size}`, inline: true },
    )
    if (message.channel) {
        moment().format();
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(serverinfocommandembed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

As you said, this is because DM channels are not in guilds, so `dmChannel.guild` will return `null`. The way you tried to fix it, by comparing the `channel.type` also works, except there is one problem: you are not stopping the execution after finding that the channel is a DM, so it just keeps on going.

Here's a simplified example of what you are doing:

```js
function isTheNumberOne(num) {
  if (num !== 1) console.log('The number is not one'); // even though the script knows the nuber isn't one
  console.log('The number is one'); // it moves right forward into saying the number is 1
};

isTheNumberOne(2)
```

What you should do is either create an `else` statement, or just `return` right there.

```js
function isTheNumberOne(num) {
  if (num !== 1)
    return console.log('The number is not one'); // stop execution
  console.log('The number is one');
};

isTheNumberOne(2)

function isTheNumberOne(num) {
  if (num !== 1)
    return console.log('The number is not one'); // only moves forward if number is not 1
  else console.log('The number is one');
};

isTheNumberOne(2)
```

You kind of tried something like this with your `if (message.channel)` statement before sending the embed, but the embed content has already loaded, and thus the bot had already run into an error, making that statement obsolete.

```js
if(message.channel.type == "dm") 
 return message.channel.send(keepinservercommandembed);
```

---

> I am hoping to get is just MM/DD/YYYY

You can use the npm package `moment` for that, which it looks like you've already imported to your file. Now all you need is to use the `format` function.

```js
{
 name: '**Joined On**:',
 value: moment(message.member.joinedAt).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
 inline: true,
},
```

Comment: thank you so much for the response. The time format worked out amazingly! And so from what I am understanding even trying to run an else statment like this

`if(message.channel.type == "dm") {
        message.channel.send(keepinservercommandembed);
    }
    else {
            message.delete();
            message.channel.send(serverinfocommandembed);
        }
    }`

would not work either? I guess I am confused on how to call it without need to access the serverinfocommandembed. I then added a return after the "if" and before "else" but still get null?

Comment: You would either need to include the entire rest of the execute function in the `else` statement, or just add a `return` before `message.channel.send(...)`. That's `return message.channel.send(serverinfocommandembed)`

Comment: amazing I figured out what you meant now. Thank you so much for all the help!!!

Comment: No problem! Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue so it's easier for people who have the same problem to find in the future!